# Reinstall R to include X11 support

Tags: r, rstudio, x11

I need X11 support for some R code. R was unfortunately explicitly configured with "--with-x=no" option. I was wondering if it is safe to re-configure, re-compile and re-install R (Centos 7) or it would trigger some errors in R-Studio or have an impact on the R-packages installed so far. I would of course use the same R version to re-install R.

Here is the output "print(capabilities())":

```
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE       FALSE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

Comment: On my MacBook I get `X11=TRUE`.  I don't think you need to reconfigure R if having `X11=TRUE` is what you need.  For my macbook, I think `xquartz` was what I needed.